# Incorrect syntax error on select statement from SQL Server using table variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure where I create a table variable and then try to execute a `select` against that table variable, but the output throws an incorrect syntax error.

I have my stored procedure (simplified) below :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetLog] 
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  Declare @Table table (ID int identity(1,1), 
                        Node varchar(100)
                       )

  insert into @Table(Node) values ('employee')

  Declare @sqlquery AS NVARCHAR(1000)

  SET @sqlquery = 'select * from @Table;'
  EXEC (@sqlquery)
```

Gives an error --

> *Incorrect syntax near '@Table'*

In reality the `@sqlquery` variable I have is complex and I need to use a variable and 
execute the query.

Is there a way I can still execute my stored procedure using a variable? Any other
suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Won't claim this as absolutely right, so I"ll post it as a comment. The Declare @TableName syntax is for table *variables*, not temp tables, and I'm thinking that the `@Table` variable is out of scope when the EXEC occurs.

Comment: @David W Thank you ! I changed the title . Yeah as you said it seems to be going out of scope . You have any suggestions or work arounds for this problem

Comment: You can declare the table using the temp table syntax, then you should be able to perform your exec. Just delete the temp table when the procedure exits.

Comment: @DavidW Thank you! Temp table solution works !

Comment: You're welcome. Wish I'd been handy to post the answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [David W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1345535/david-w) mentioned in his comment, just use a temp table (not a table variable) if you want something that is visible within your EXEC scope:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (ID int identity(1,1), 
                    Node varchar(100)
                   )
insert into #Table(Node) values ('employee')

Declare @sqlquery AS NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @sqlquery = 'select * from #Table;'
EXEC (@sqlquery)

DROP TABLE #Table;
```

Comment: Than you David W and Nick Jones. My first post on stackoverflow.
This works !
For someone else having the same question you can refer the link below .
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/temp-tables-vs-variables/

table variables exist only in the same scope as variables. Contrary to the temporary tables, they are not visible in inner stored procedures and in exec(string) statements. Also, they cannot be used in an insert/exec statement.